# GUI does not start, xorg log shows errors

Tags: xorg

I am stuck with a black screen when booting 14.04. I can log in via CLI but cannot start the GUI. I have tried the standard [fixes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) to no avail.  I have tried installing lightdm, and removing and changing permissions of `.Xauthority` but this made no difference.

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` contains the following errors:

```
[   327.953] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[   327.970] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   327.987] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   328.035] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[   328.263] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Certainly looks like an Nvidia driver problem. Have you tried booting with `nomodeset` kernel option to check that it's this graphics card error that is source of the issue? If installing the proprietary driver, have you tried to remove the `nvidia-glx` and `linux-restricted-modules` packages then re-running proprietary installer ? (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=808247&p=5228977#post5228977)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand this error shows that your Nvidia driver has a problem. Did you figure out that you have the driver or not ? You can check it by typing

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-*
```

and see what results do you have. You can also reinstall xorg-xserver so it may solve but your problem.

Comment: It was the NVidia driver. I followed the instructions [here](https://codeyarns.com/2013/02/07/how-to-fix-nvidia-driver-failure-on-ubuntu/) to fix it. Thanks!